The Legendre transform is a convex function
I am new at the study of Hamiltonian Mechanics and I am facing the definition of Legendre transformation. I know that the Legendre transformation of a convex function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined as:
$$f^*(p)=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}(px-f(x)).$$
In his "Mathematical methods of Classical Mechanics" Arnold claims that $f^*$ is a convex function. I am trying to prove it using the geometric definition of a convex function (I do not want to assume special properties of regularity on the function $f$), but I am having some troubles:
$f^*((1-t)p+tq)=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}([(1-t)p+tq]x-f(x))=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}((1-t)px+tqx-f(x)-f(x)+f(x))=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}((1-t)px-f(x)+tqx-f(x)+f(x))\leq (1-t)f^*(p)+tf^*(q)+\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(x)$, for $t\in (0,1)$.
I am not able to get rid of that $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(x)$...

You were correct so far, however you mishandled the last step. Writing shortly $\sup \equiv \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}$, it is
$$(1-t)f^{\ast}(p) = (1-t) \sup [ px - f(x) ] = \sup [ (1-t)px - (1-t)f(x)]$$
So your prove must actually proceed like this:
$$ \begin{align} f^{\ast}\big( (1-t)p + tq \big) \enspace &= \enspace \sup \Big[  \Big((1-t)p + tq \Big)x - f(x) \Big] \\
&{} \\
&= \enspace \sup \Big[ (1-t)px - f(x) + tqx \underbrace{- tf(x) + tf(x)}_{\text{adds zero}} \Big] \\
&{} \\
&= \enspace \sup \Big[ (1-t)px - (1-t)f(x) + tqx - tf(x) \Big] \\
&{} \\
&= \enspace \sup \Big[ (1-t)\big( px - f(x) \big) + t \big( qx - f(x) \big) \Big] \\
&{} \\
&\leq \enspace (1-t) \sup \Big[ px - f(x) \Big] + t \sup \Big[ qx - f(x) \Big] \\
&{} \\
&\leq \enspace (1-t) f^{\ast}(p) + t f^{\ast}(q) \end{align}$$
which is the desired result.

Note that the Legendre-Fenchel transform $f^{\ast}$ is convex even if $f$ is not.
Sketched proof:

Define $$h(x,p):=xp-f(x)\tag{1}$$ and $$f^{\ast}(p):=\sup_{x\in I}h(x,p).\tag{2}$$
Then $$h(x,tp+(1-t)q)~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~ t h(x,p)+(1-t)h(x,q).\tag{3}$$
Then $$\begin{align}f^{\ast}(tp+(1-t)q)~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~&\sup_{x\in I}h(x,tp+(1-t)q)\cr~\stackrel{(3)}{\leq}~& t\sup_{x\in I}h(x,p)+(1-t)\sup_{y\in I}h(y,q)\cr~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~&tf^{\ast}(p)+(1-t)f^{\ast}(q).\tag{4}\end{align}$$
$\Box$

